Alternatives to still-face paradigm for eliciting several levels of emotional stress in infants and their caregivers
I'm designing an experiment for assessing parental verbal utterances to 7 months old infants under emotional stress. Surely, still-face paradigm is the first choice for a stress inducing context. But I would like to use a second paradigm for eliciting stress arousal in the dyad, maybe one that allows eliciting different levels of stress. Are there any other paradigms that I could use for child age of 7 months? If not: are there variations of still–face paradigm that may allow different levels of stress?
